# read_table handling missing strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

While trying to import data from a .txt file using pandas `read_table()`, I came across an interesting issue.

The file contains a column only partly filled with strings (**OrigVol**). The empty cells are then filled with values from the following column and NaNs are added at the end, where this shift leads to empty cells. The image below shows the result of using `pd.read_table( file.txt, sep = r'\s+')` after `import pandas as pd`.

[image]

The column **OrigVol** should contain empty strings, or NaN's, instead of the column **prim_pos_eutags**. 
I'm new to panda and it's diffcult to come up with a MWE that exactly reproduces the problem. One would need the file (which I couldn't upload).

Maybe I missed to specify an import option. Let me know if more information is required.

Any hints are much appreciated!

According to the suggestion, I provide the first 8 lines of an example file

```
Name            Subtype     ProcName            Material    Creator     OrigVol trklen                  prim_pos_eutags
top             0           initStep            undefined   undefined   top     0                       prim_pos_eudata
top             91          Transportation      Vacuum      undefined           2.27009877562523E-12    prim_pos_eudata
QC5L_2_v        91          Transportation      Vacuum      undefined           3.50000000000227        prim_pos_eudata
DRIFT_8609_v    91          Transportation      Vacuum      undefined           3.80000000000518        prim_pos_eudata
BC1L_2_v        23          SynRad              Vacuum      undefined           68.1607816456518        prim_pos_eudata
BC1L_2_v        91          Transportation      Vacuum      undefined           79.0910350747966        prim_pos_eudata
DRIFT_8610_v    91          Transportation      Vacuum      undefined   QC2_v   79.3910346856657        prim_pos_eudata
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are separated with variable number of spaces to make the columns look nice and aligned in the text file. What you can do instead is to read the file line by line, split the line and see if the number of elements in the list generated with `line.split()` are less than number of columns. If yes, than add an empty string at the required index.

```
input_file  = open('test.txt', "rb")
data = []
for line in input_file:
    splitted_list = line.split()
    if len(splitted_list) < 8: # 8 is number of columns, change it if it is wrong
        splitted_list.insert(5, "") # add an empty string inn the 5th column (change the number if it is wrong)
        data.append(splitted_list)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the information. I already had the suspicion it might be related to the specified separator. However, falling back to a single white-space won't do the trick, I'm afraid.
Usually, within the whole file multiple white-spaces are used as separators.

Comment: Thanks for notifying. Did you check with `'\s`? If yes, can you share at least one row of data? May be change some values and then share? It's super tough to make wild guesses.

Comment: A brief check using `' '` as well as `\s` seemed not to work. I provided an example file as an edit to my original post. Wild guessing is indeed not very helpful ;) Thanks.

Comment: yeah, just checked it, sadly a bad example of data acquisition. The columns are separated with variable number of spaces to make the columns look nice and aligned in  the text file. Still thinking what can be done to handle the case.
Is it the only column which has missing values? Some hack can be thought if that is the case.

Comment: Indeed it is not the best example for a data file. Fortunately, it is the only column where there's partially no data.

Comment: Great, I will tell you the hint quickly, Need some time to code it though. Before reading it through table, you could split line using .split() function and count the number of elements after split, it is 1 less than  the number of columns, you know where to add an empty string or NaN whatever you want.

Comment: Added the code as well, hopefully, it shall work. Looking to hear back :)

Comment: Hi, just gave it a try. With some minor changes, it solves the problem -- see the post below. 
Am I right in assuming the only clean and more robust solution would be to change the input file to another format using tabs or single white-spaces as separators?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestions by [Anant Mittal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12266923/anant-mittal), the problem could be solved.

However, I did some minor changes to achieve a clean data frame with the first line as header.

```
input_file  = open('test.txt', "r")
data = []
for line in input_file:
    splitted_list = line.split()

    if len(splitted_list) == 8: data.append( splitted_list )
    if len(splitted_list) < 8: # 8 is number of columns, change it if it is wrong
        splitted_list.insert(5, "") # add an empty string inn the 5th column (change the number if it is wrong)
        data.append(splitted_list)

test = pd.DataFrame.from_records( data )

# first row to select header
header = test.iloc[0] 
# exclude first line 
test = test[1:] 
# reset the header
test.columns = header
test
```